# yii2 how to use search on a column having mix values some from database and some dummies

Tags: php, yii, phpmyadmin, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to search for a field having values some from database and one as dummy if database has null value. The problem is that the value from database can be searched but the dummy value return no result found. i am not sure how to use condition to make it possible to search from database if not found then return the dummy value columns. Here is the `index.php` code

```
[
    'attribute'=>'tenant_user_id',
    'label' => 'Tenant Name',
    'value' => function($model) {
        if(isset($model->tenant_user_id)){
                    return $model->tenantUser->first_name;
        }else{
            return 'General Voucher';

        }
    },
],
```

[image]

Comment: if values are not found in db you don't have  row in gridview and the function for return values can't be executed ..

Comment: i am getting above rows in gridview. sajid is from database and general voucher is dummy. i am not sure how to use search for the dummy value? i can filter sajid but can't general voucher!

Comment: update you question add   a proper data sample  .. and the expected  result .. (your question is not clear)

Comment: i want to filter tenant names. here is code snippet .....  ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tenant.first_name', $this->tenant_user_id])
           // ->andFilterWhere(['like','tenant.first_name','General Voucher'])
            /*->andFilterWhere([
                'or',
                ['like', 'tenant.first_name', $this->tenant_user_id],
                ['like', 'General Voucher', $this->tenant_user_id]
            ])*/..

Comment: but the problem is that while filtering the value from database as sajid is here can be filtered out but value not present in database as general voucher can't be filter out , giving no result found out put.

Comment: I can't understand  whta do you mean .. if the values are not in database then  how you think of filter these values ..for filter  the gridview use a dataprovider build by related modelSearch class and search function .. take a look at this so you can eval how the filter work on db ..

Comment: if the values are not in database there is no way to filter them then. okay got it. Thank you so much